# The 'pip==9.0.3' distribution was not found and is required by the application

Tags: pip

I have the latest version of pip in my laptop.I always get this error when I install any modules using pip.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site- 
    packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3195, in <module>
    @_call_aside
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site- 
    packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3179, in _call_aside
   (*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-p 
    packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3208, in _ 
    initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site- 
    packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 681, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site- 
   packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 999, in require
   needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site- 
   packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 885, in resolve
   raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==9.0.3' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

How do I resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you have `/usr/bin/pip` and it works.

```
/usr/bin/pip --version
/usr/bin/pip install …
```

Then remove `/usr/local/bin/pip` and make bash to rehash the `$PATH`: `hash -r`.